# Can't change Powershell ExecutionPolicy of User Account

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, powershell-3.0

Typing `Get-ExecutionPolicy` in PowerShell as Administrator returns **Restricted**, but when I run Powershell as User Account and type `Get-ExecutionPolicy` it returns **Unrestricted**. Why is that ? I thougt setting the ExecutionPolicy to Restricted in PowerShell as Administrator would also change the ExecutionPolicy of the User Account. Is this normal or am I doing something wrong ? How can I change the Execution Policy from my Group Policy ?

As Administrator Account
[image: powershell as admin]

As User Acount
[image: powershell as user]

Answer (score 1):

The per-user scope of the Powershell execution policy overrides the machine-wide value, like
most user preferences do. In order to enforce a given policy on users or machines, you
must enable the appropriate Group Policy setting (shown in your powershell output as the
MachinePolicy and UserPolicy scopes) See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849812.aspx.

Comment: So how can i do this ? I have to do it from my Group Policy bu where is the setting ?